# Which thread is using a given object?

Tags: c#, multithreading, windbg, sos

1. I run `dumpheap -type MyObjectType` command to get the method table for `MyObjectType`. It shows three object on heap.
2. I run `dumpheap -mt <method table address>` to get address.
3. I run `!gcroot <address>` command to find the references to these objects, find nothing
4. `!do <address>` and it provides details about fields for this object etc.

How can I find which thread is referencing or using object? Any command to find that out?

Comment: Do you think objects are assigned to particular thread which holds a link on it?

Comment: Threads do not own objects but they can access it if able to get reference to object.

Comment: Well any object will instantiated based on certain methods been called on a particular thread stack. I just want to narrow down object and the method that is instatinating (or hold reference) to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy way to do this, but you could run `!dso` for each thread (i.e. `~*!dso`). That will tell you which objects each of the threads reference. To help navigate the output I usually log it to a file and use grep or a decent text editor to search the results.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to use [Microsoft's CLR Profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16273) to find out which thread allocated and accessed your object. I'm not sure if `!gcroot` shows objects waiting for finalizer, but CLR Profiler definitely does. Your object also might be not referenced from any GC root at all and it's just waiting for collection to occur. It can take quite some time especially if it is allocated in LOB heap. Try forcing a few GCs (and see if gen0-2 collections actually took place) and see if your object survives.

Comment: well i am looking into dump file and i don't know if a dump file can be consumed by CLR profiler

Comment: It can't - CLR Profiler needs to be attached to live process. If it was one-time event, my guess would be that object was just waiting for GC to happen.